# Left Excluding JOIN Not working

Tags: mysql

I have two SQL queries.

```
Select * from users (Returns 74 rows)

id      firstname       lastname
1       vignesh         km
2       hariram         v
3       vijesh          g
.
.
74      ram             k


Select * from details where time between '2017-05-11 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-11 23:59:59' (Returns 5 row).


id      userid      logindate   
57      1           2017-05-11 09:07:23
63      3           2017-05-11 09:04:57
65      6           2017-05-11 09:14:45
83      13          2017-05-11 09:26:43
65      74          2017-05-11 09:11:53
```

i tried

```
SELECT *
FROM details dt LEFT JOIN users us ON us.id = dt.userid
WHERE dt.logindate BETWEEN '2017-05-11 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-11 23:59:59' OR dt.userid IS NULL
GROUP BY dt.userid; (6 rows returning - in that one row contains full of null)
```

AND

```
SELECT *
FROM details dt LEFT JOIN users us ON us.id = dt.userid
WHERE dt.logindate BETWEEN '2017-05-11 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-11 23:59:59'
GROUP BY dt.userid; (5 rows returning)


id      userid      logindate               firstname       lastname
57      1           2017-05-11 09:07:23     vignesh         km
63      3           2017-05-11 09:04:57     vijesh          g
65      6           2017-05-11 09:14:45     ..              ..
83      13          2017-05-11 09:26:43     ..              ..
65      74          2017-05-11 09:11:53     ram             k
```

Both are not working. But I need the 69 rows which are available in 1st query result and not available in the 2nd query result.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM details dt LEFT JOIN users us ON us.id = dt.userid
WHERE dt.userid IS NOT NULL AND dt.logindate BETWEEN '2017-04-26 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-26 23:59:59'`

Comment: @Nimish Looks like an answer, why do you put it into a comment?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7393748/nimish the query you sent also returning 5 rows only

Comment: What is unsure and why do you not use comments to clarify your doubts?

Comment: Now check Edited query

Comment: @Vignesh clarify your question by providing sample input, desired output and more details on what you want.

Comment: Make a [mcve], it should include a `.dump` from sqlite commandline tool, defining a useable toy database. You obviously had "only 5 rows" as one of your unwanted results, please explain, using the data in the toy db as reference.

Comment: Please confirm login date is 11 may or 26 April ?

Comment: sorry, its 11th may. I tried with different days.

Comment: have a look `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT userid
    FROM details dt
    WHERE dt.userid IS NOT NULL AND dt.logindate BETWEEN '2017-05-11 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-11 23:59:59');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I don't know why you're using `group by`, if you want to fetch `users` records which not exist in `details`, you can try this:

```
select *
from users u
left join details d on u.id = d.userid
and d.logindate BETWEEN '2017-05-11 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-11 23:59:59'
where d.id is null
```

or use `not exists`

```
select *
from users u
where not exists (
    select 1
    from details d
    where u.id = d.userid
    and d.logindate BETWEEN '2017-05-11 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-11 23:59:59'
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * from users us 
left join  details  dt on us.id=dt.userid
WHERE dt.logindate NOT BETWEEN '2017-04-26 00:00:00' AND
'2017-04-26 23:59:59' GROUP BY dt.userid
```

Comment: there is one more problem in this answer. if the user details are not available in details table at all i won't get that user.

Comment: you will get the user because it is left join.if user is not present in details than you will get null. i have taken user first than details. so  i think you will get  users

Answer (score -1):

Don't use GROUP BY

```
SELECT * FROM details dt 
LEFT JOIN users us ON us.id = dt.userid 
WHERE dt.userid IS NOT NULL AND dt.logindate 
BETWEEN '2017-05-11 00:00:00' AND '2017-05-11 23:59:59
```

Comment: @down_voters, post the valid reason for down voting.